# How can I use Beautiful Soup to get the value from a dictionary that is inside of a <script> tag

Tags: beautifulsoup

How can I use Beautiful Soup to get a value of `productId` from the following `<script>` tag

```
soup.find('script')
<script>
    gtmData.productData['34597834'] = {

        "productId": 1234,
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": 2,
    }
<script>
```

I want to retrieve the value of `productId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you can print the `soup` object as a text.

```py
import re
data = """gtmData.productData['34597834'] = {

    "productId": 1234,
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2,
}"""

print(re.search(r"productId\": (\d*)", data).group(1))
```

Output:

```
1234
```

Also there's several ways, such as load it in `JSON` to parse whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, with no regex:

```
scr = """[your script above]"""
items = scr.split('{')[1].split('}')[0].split(',')
for item in items:
    if ':' in item:
        product = item.split(': ')
        print(product[0].strip(), product[1])
```

Output:

```
"productId" 1234
"foo" 1
"bar" 2
```